# Live API fails intermittently

Tags: live

I've been using the API to retreive user information for many months now.  Today it is intermittently timing out.  Who do I contact for support on this?

**https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=[TOKEN]**

Answer (score 0):

it's part of the microsoft office 365 api, so the vendor is microsoft.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659736.aspx

microsoft links to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-office tag for this api, so you should also add this tag to the question.

maybe you find help in the microsoft blog https://blogs.office.com/dev/